# MFC Remove All Static Split Panes (1x1 View)

Tags: mfc

I have used CreateStatic & CreateView to split "C(classname)View" into many panes (like (1x2), (3x3)) using button control to choose the number of rows and columns.

Now, when I click 1x1 (which means I want to remove any panes), ASSERT(n_Row > 1 && n_Col > 1) obviously fails inside CSplitterWnd::CreateStatic.

How do I handle the "no-panes" situation?

This is the DisplaySingleFrame() Function (which removes the panes)

```
CN00bSplitApp* pApp = (CN00bSplitApp*)AfxGetApp();
CView * pActiveView = NULL;

if(pActiveView == NULL)
{
if(m_pSplitter)
    pActiveView = (CView*)m_pSplitter->GetPane(0,0);
        else
    pActiveView = (CN00bSplitView *)GetActiveView();
}

m_iPrevColLayout = m_iRowLayout;
m_iPrevRowLayout = m_iColLayout;

m_iRowLayout = 0;
m_iColLayout = 0;

ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);

CRect rect(0,0,0,0);
pActiveView->GetClientRect(rect);
CDocument * pDoc= pActiveView->GetDocument();

pActiveView->DestroyWindow();

pActiveView = NULL;

if(m_pSplitter)
{
m_pSplitter->DestroyWindow();
delete m_pSplitter;
m_pSplitter = NULL;
}

CDocTemplate* pDocTemplate = pApp->m_pDocTemplate;

CCreateContext context;

context.m_pNewViewClass= RUNTIME_CLASS(CN00bSplitView);
context.m_pCurrentDoc=(CN00bSplitDoc*)pDocTemplate->CreateNewDocument();
context.m_pLastView=pActiveView;

CView* p = (CView*)CreateView(&context, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST);
SetActiveView(p);

p->OnInitialUpdate();

RecalcLayout();
ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

This throws an unhandled exception at "context.m_pCurrentDoc=(CN00bSplitDoc*)pDocTemplate->CreateNewDocument();"

Comment: pDocTemplate is NULL. So it will obviously throw an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't initialized `m_pDocTemplate=pDocTemplate` in the InitInstance of the `C(classname)App`.

Solves the problem.